How to combine streams from different AI APIs and process in near-realtime
Context:
I am trying to create a conversational bot that does following:

Listens to my speech & converts it to text STT (AssemblyAi API)
Then sends my text to LLM model and recieves the response in stream
(OpenAi assistant API)
Then the response from OpenAi (step is converted to speech TTS (Elevenlabs)

Now as you can see it is already slow, so I started using Streaming option from OpenAi, so that response from AI is bit faster! I implemented it.
problem:
Now that I am streaming response from OpenAI, the step 3 function i.e. the one that converts AI response into Audio (TTS) is not executed because it actually keeps waiting for streaming in step 2 to be done! I want the TTS part from ElevenLabs to be streamed too!
Question:
I want to convert the streaming response from step 2 to be converted into speech in realtime. i.e. step 3 to happen in streaming way too!
Code:
 # Stream the response using the EventHandler
        event_handler = AIEventHandler(self)

        with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
            thread_id=thread.id,
            assistant_id=assistant_id,
            event_handler=event_handler,
        ) as stream:
            stream.until_done()

        self.start_transcription()
        print(f"\nReal-time transcription:")

    # Generate audio with 11Labs
    def generate_audio(self, ai_response):
        self.full_transcript.append({"role": "assistant", "content": ai_response})
        print(f"\nCandidate: {ai_response}")

        audio_stream = generate(
            api_key=self.elevenlabs_api_key,
            text=ai_response,
            stream=True
        )

        stream(audio_stream)

# Initialize and start the assistant
greeting = "Hi Thank you for having me here."
ai_assistant = AI_Assistant()
ai_assistant.generate_audio(greeting)
ai_assistant.start_transcription()

Now I can see what is wrong! But how to go about solution?
